# Using Strophe.js with ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmpp, react-native, strophe

I am trying to build a ReactNative chat app. The backend consists of a Prosody XMPP/Bosh server. Now I want to connect by using the Strophe.js Javascript library. The problem that I have is that the Strophe.js library depends on the global `document` variable for generating XML nodes. Did anyone of you already have the same problem or has a clue how might get it working?

Comment: Hey sebbo, I know it's been a while since you asked, but did you managed to make it work? I would love to have a quick chat with you to discuss this if you're up to it, it would help me greatly!
Cheers

Comment: Hi @PrettyGoodPancake unfortunately I couldn't find an easy way to make it work so I basically switched to a third party messaging service (sendbird.com)

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp ? I think a NodeJS lib is more likely to work in RN.

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution:
Im using a ReactNative WebView running parallel and not Visible to my ReactNativeApp, similar to this Crypto (but with ReactNativeWebview! not  React Native WebView Javascript Bridge)

In the WebView you can use Strophe, you just need to write a Wrapper for the Communication between RN and Strophe in the WebView.

I'll try to make gitRepo with a working Basic Version

(Check the Crypto Example:
https://github.com/saulshanabrook/react-native-webview-crypto
)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few xmpp javscript libraries which may work with react-native.
But they require further configuration.

There are also quite actively maintained xmpp libraries for react native.
[XMPP.js](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js?locale=pl) is one of them. They also provide plugin support.
But, they are quite early in development and of course libraries like strophe.js are much more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript engine used in ReactNative is headless, meaning it does not provide global objects like `navigator`, `document`, `location`, etc. Other than that the browser is fully functional and has all `XHR` functionalities of a normal browser.

Storephe's communication with the server is all based on XHR requests. You only need to mock the document object to prevent Strophe from raising an exception when it can't find the `document` object. [mock-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser) build for that exact reason. A simple example of how to use it:

```
let MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
let mock = new MockBrowser();
GLOBAL.window = mock.getWindow()
GLOBAL.document = mock.getDocument()
GLOBAL.navigator = mock.getNavigator()
```

Comment: Hey @bman, have you tried this solution? I cannot seem to make it work at all using RN. Would you mind sharing a bit more code on how to get started with Strophe + Mock-browser? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, have you found any working xmpp client solution for react native?